# Creating audio file in internal memory in Android

Tags: android, audio, voice-recording

I want the audio file created during audio capture to be stored in the internal memory and played back from there. I am getting media player prepare failed() when trying to do so

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do this using `MediaRecorder`. First add the correct permissions (you will need to add more if you choose to use external storage).

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

This records the audio in internal storage:

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(getFilesDir()+"/audio.m4a");
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start(); 
...
recorder.stop();
recorder.reset();
recorder.release()
```

This plays the audio from internal storage:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getFilesDir()+"/audio.m4a");
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

`getFilesDir()` gives you the path to your internal files. Here's a link to more information on data storage, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal.